# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor Syntax - Casting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So, simple question really. :)

I had this following code with **ASPX View Engine**:

```
<strong><%: ((City)Model.Location).Name %></strong>
```

Which renders
**Los Angeles**

If i do this with **Razor View Engine:**

```
<strong>@((City)Model.Location).Name</strong>
                             ^
                             |
syntax highlighting stops here
```

It renders this:

**(really huge object name must be .ToString).Name**

So, the highlighting cuts off at **Location)**, and it's treating the **.Name** code i have (which is a property on a **City** object) as pure HTML.

Why is it deeming the **)** as the end of the Razor code block?

Any ideas?

Also - is there a Razor reference which has all the syntax/keywords? (it took me a while to figure out that `<% Import Namespace` is `@using` with Razor).

Thanks Guys!

Comment: @Downvoter - care to explain why?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Does `<strong>@(((City)Model.Location).Name)</strong>` work? I think it's thinking the expression contained within `@()` is closed.

Comment: Haha, yeah that works. Cheers. If in doubt, add another bracket. :) Will accept your answer in 7 minutes. :)

Comment: As far as docs go, I haven't seen anything official yet. The Gu's blog is probably the best place currently http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx

Comment: Yep, read that. Yeah we really need a definitive source. I basically guessed the @using statement. :)

Comment: @rpm Yes, that is expected behavior. If the "@" is followed by a "(" then the expression will *always* end at the matching ")". The solution is what John showed, which is to add an extra set of parentheses around the entire expression.

Answer (score 12):

Also, for slightly easier reading...

```
<strong>@( (Model.Location as City).Name )</strong>
```