# Print a variable on the screen using Razor (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I want to print a variable on the screen using Razor. I have a class named CustomPrincipal saved in the HttpContext, which is saved correctly.

I want it to have it on one line like the example below, which is unfortunately not working:

```
@* This is not working... *@
@(CustomPrincipal)Context.Items["IUser"].Name
```

The example below is working though, so it saved it correctly to the HttpContext.

```
@{ CustomPrincipal user = (CustomPrincipal)Context.Items["IUser"]; }
@user.Name
```

Does anyone know why the first example is not working and can you show me a solution?

The error is:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0118: 'CustomPrincipal' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you have an error message? Is nothing displayed?

Comment: Read [ask], elaborate on "not working" and share your research. It's a parenthesis issue, you can't cast the string `Name` to `CustomPrincipal`.

Comment: You probably just need to wrap the `CustomPrincipal` object in parens, otherwise it will try to cast the entire line to that type: `@(((CustomPrincipal)Context.Items["IUser"]).Name)`

Comment: @DavidG That is not working either, then it just prints the string "CustomPrincipal.Name" to the screen.

Comment: @DavidG one more set of parentheses. The `@(...)` format will print just `...`, so that you can prepend and append text that might look like C# code.

Comment: @CodeCaster Of course, good spot.

Comment: @YanickvanBarneveld Try again

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick: "@(((CustomPrincipal)Context.Items["IUser"]).Name)". Forgot the last set of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

All the credits go to @DavidG and @CodeCaster, mentioned in the comments.

```
@(((CustomPrincipal)Context.Items["IUser"]).Name)
```

The parentheses where required because otherwise there is no `Name` property on the `Object` type which is what `Context.Items["IUser"]` is. We have to add parentheses to cast that `Object` to `CustomPrincipal` first, then access the `Name` property of that type.

Another example of the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4151988/4585226

Comment: The first example on the question doesn't work because it is trying to cast the `Name` property of the `Object Context.Items["IUser"]` to the `CustomPrincipal` type, at least that is what is being interpreted. Your example works because it casts the `Object` to `CustomPrincipal` first, then accesses the `Name` property of the `CustomPrincipal` type.